# ontouch() listener on volume control?

Tags: android, volume, ontouchlistener

I've been trying to make an app that disable volume changes. I already make it for volume up and volume down buttons. But I realize the volume can still be changed through touching the screen after volume button pressed.. 
I was thinking on disabling the volume control pop up but it seems a dead end. Then I thought on ontouchlistener. Then the problem is that ontouch listener only called when I touch the activity, not the volume control.

Is it possible to have ontouchlistener on volume control?
Or maybe other thoughts? Either is okay

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control or intercept touch events on the volume dialog, as it is part of the system UI and not your app.

You could use WindowManager to draw an arbitrary layout over the volume dialog that can consume the touch events, but you'd have to add and remove it very quickly, so that it only exists when the dialog does. If you keep it present even when the dialog isn't there, you will render that part of the screen unusable.

Generally, apps like this are an Android anti pattern, as the user should always be in control of their device.

Comment: That sounds tricky and may not work on some slower device. thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

you can try one thing. To disable you can override the keyevent of volume keys like below

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN
            || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I already done that. But the volume can still be changed by adjusting it via sliding volume dialog bar